# New object type render on render() method?

Tags: android, libgdx, clone

I am looking for creating new objects everytime while touching screen or clicking mouse, or every time user inputs. I had some ideas just like cloning, creating new, or adding in ArrayList. Something like:

```
if (Gdx.input.JustTouched){ shapeRenderer.circle(Gdx.input.getX(),Gdx.input.getY(),10); }
```

But everytime when is touched, draws a new circle. I have tried with:

```
private Object[] appendValue(Object[] obj, Object newObj) {

    ArrayList<Object> temp = new ArrayList<Object>(Arrays.asList(obj));
    temp.add(newObj);
    return temp.toArray();
```

But I cannot assign a void method (shapeRenderer.circle) to an object, so didn't work for me. other way was doing the draw outside the if, passing the coordinates, but keeps in the render loop and then gets lost the coordinates. Is it possible to clone methods and get new draws? If this was answered, please tell me and I'll delete this question, I'm really lost

Comment: This question is very hard to understand, I'll try to answer it but correct me if I have not understood it correctly.

Comment: Just want to draw a new shape everytime when is touched, keeping the last touches. Meaning, adding new shapes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The method `shapeRenderer.circle(float x, float y, float radius)` draws a circle on the canvas. It does not create an object, it creates a bunch of pixels on the canvas, which are lost as soon as the canvas is redrawn.

You need to store the data that you would pass into the `circle` method, so that you can redraw your old circles, and add more on touch events. A good way to do that would be to define a class `Circle`:

```
public class Circle {
    public float x;
    public float y;
    public float radius;

    public Circle(float x, float y, float radius) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        this.radius = radius;
    }
}
```

Then you can create a list of these circles, and add a new one every time you detect a touch event:

```
if (Gdx.input.JustTouched)
    circles.add(new Circle(Gdx.input.getX(),Gdx.input.getY(),10));
```

And whenever you need to redraw the screen, draw *all* the circles:

```
for (Circle circle : circles)
    shapeRenderer.circle(circle.x, circle.y, circle.radius);
```

**EDIT**

Your code was crashing, because your collection of Circles was null, and you call `circles.add`. That will throw a null pointer exception unless you instantiate `circles` properly.

```
public class MyGdxGame implements ApplicationListener
{
    ShapeRenderer shapeRenderer;
    OrthographicCamera camera;

    // It's a collection specifically of Circles. Also, there's one per game, so don't make it static.
    Collection<Circle> circles;

    @Override
    public void create()
    {       
        camera = new OrthographicCamera();
        configureCamera();
        shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();

        // Make it an empty collection to begin with
        circles = new ArrayList<Circle>();
    }

    @Override
    public void render()
    {       
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        camera.update();
        shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
        shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);

        shapeRenderer.setColor(0, 0.5f, 0, 1);
        shapeRenderer.circle(50, 50, 40);

        shapeRenderer.setColor(0.5f, 0, 0, 1);
        shapeRenderer.rect(10, 100, 80, 80);

        shapeRenderer.setColor(0, 0, 0.5f, 1);
        shapeRenderer.triangle(10, 200, 90, 200, 50, 270);

        // Check for input, and add the new circle, *before* drawing all the circles
        if (Gdx.input.justTouched())
            circles.add(new Circle(Gdx.input.getX(),Gdx.input.getY(),10));

        for (Circle circle : circles)
            shapeRenderer.circle(circle.x, circle.y, circle.radius);

        shapeRenderer.end();
    }

    // *static* - Google the difference between inner vs nested classes
    public static class Circle {
        public float x;
        public float y;
        public float radius;

        public Circle(float x, float y, float radius) {
            this.x = x;
            this.y = y;
            this.radius = radius;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Think you guessed what I'm trying to, but this didn't worked. Don't know were, but when running, breaks and shuts down. Reason? Don't know

Comment: Can you post the code for your ApplicationListener class?

Comment: Sure, I've made in a temp tutorial code, cause mine is really a mess:

Comment: Okay, I've edited to show the main point that was making it crash.

Comment: That worked for me, now I've to do some other stuff. I really appreciate your help

Answer (score 0):

Think I'll do here:

```
public class MyGdxGame implements ApplicationListener
{
ShapeRenderer shapeRenderer;
OrthographicCamera camera;
static Collection circles;

@Override
public void create()
{       
camera = new OrthographicCamera();
configureCamera();
circles = null;

shapeRenderer = new ShapeRenderer();
}

@Override
public void render()
{       
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

camera.update();
shapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(camera.combined);
shapeRenderer.begin(ShapeRenderer.ShapeType.Filled);

shapeRenderer.setColor(0, 0.5f, 0, 1);
shapeRenderer.circle(50, 50, 40);

shapeRenderer.setColor(0.5f, 0, 0, 1);
shapeRenderer.rect(10, 100, 80, 80);

shapeRenderer.setColor(0, 0, 0.5f, 1);
shapeRenderer.triangle(10, 200, 90, 200, 50, 270);


for (Circle circle : circles)
shapeRenderer.circle(circle.x, circle.y, circle.radius);

if (Gdx.input.justTouched())
    circles.add(new Circle(Gdx.input.getX(),Gdx.input.getY(),10));

shapeRenderer.end();
}


public class Circle {
   public float x;
   public float y;
   public float radius;

public Circle(float x, float y, float radius) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.radius = radius;
}
}
}
```